# How to make angles in degrees \ang{} bold when I use \rowstyle{\bfseries}

Tags: fonts, siunitx

When I use `\rowstyle{\bfseries}` to make a few rows bold in my tables, I have one column in degrees. I need the degree signs. If I could have degrees signs by other methods other than `\ang{}` and it would solve the problem (`\ang{}` doesn't allow any bold font), it would be great. But I don't think so. And I don't think `\ang{}` allows any other command.
Now my rows look like this:

[image: wrong table format]

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you're talking about `siunitx`'s `\ang` then check if you passed the `detect-all` option to the package or the setup macro (that may help).

Comment: As @samcarter is saying, it's hard to give a definite answer, but perhaps adding `\boldmath` to `\rowstyle` solves the issue. `\boldmath` is contained in the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @marmot `\boldmath` does not require `amsmath`, it comes with core LaTeX.

Comment: I've tried them before, none of them worked. \boldmath$\ang{48.8}$

Comment: @TeXnician \sisetup{detect-all} worked perfectly well!　Ｔｈａｎｋ　ｙｏｕ！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using `siunitx` you have to enable it's "font context checks". The package offers you the option `detect-all` (which will adjust the font completely to the surrounding text) and, i.a., `detect-weight` (which is the only component needed for `\bfseries`).

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant of solutions but if you add the `amsbsy` package you can put `$\pmb{^{\circ}}$` next to every number. Hopefully there is a better way, but at least it gets the job done.